# Integrating PHPmailer with Ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ses

Hello I have this code to send mail but mail is not getting sent. I can not send mail from the online server but I can send mail locally. What could be the issue?

```
$mail = new \Core\mailer\Phpmailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); // we are going to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true; // enabled SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls"; 
$mail->Host       = "email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com";     
$mail->Port       = 587;                   // SMTP port to connect to GMail
$mail->Username   = "******";  // user email address
$mail->Password   = "*********";            // password in GMail
$mail->SetFrom('upload@irokingdev.com', 'IROKING');  //Who is sending the email
$mail->AddReplyTo('upload@irokingdev.com', 'iROKING Registration');  
$mail->Subject    = 'Registration on iROKING';
$mail->Body      = $body;
$mail->AltBody    = "Plain text message";
$destination = $to; // Who is addressed the email to
$mail->AddAddress($destination, "");

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo  "Message sent correctly!";
}
```

Comment: Are any errors generated?

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna take a stab at and say that you are probably missing your email address `upload@irokingdev.com`  as a verified email address in Amazon SES.

You can do it from AWS SES console:

[image: SES Verify Email]